# Table Names in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, tablename, vba

In the Name Manager, I have a few Table Names defined: A, B, C and D.
Now, I want to check which formulas in the current workbook that contain one particular table name, say C. How I can check it apart from opening all formulas via the shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>)?

Or can I create such a formula via VBA?

Comment: `Home` ► `Editing` ► `Find & Select` ► `Find All`  Be sure to check `Look in Formulas`

Answer (score 1):

Please see images below. I am unable to comment on Ron Rosenfeld's comment due to lack of reputation points. But since that solution is incomplete, I am providing complete solution below.

See sample data taken by me -

[image]

Go to Home > Editing > Find & Select > Formulas

[image]

It will select formulas. Now go to Home > Styles > Conditional Formatting > EQUAL TO  and give the exact data you want to see

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.